# Does opencv for tegra (Jetson TK1) make use of npp and openvx underneath?

Tags: opencv, nvidia, tegra, npp, openvx

Does OpenCv for Tegra devices supplied with Linux 4 Tegra make use of NPP and OpenVX underneath ? Or do I have to make such optimizations myself ?

Any reference to a link pointing to proof would be appreciated.

Comment: afair in OpenCV4Tegra you have access to source codes but not to the tegra function code (only binaries there). So you can look at the source code and try to find npp or openvx "calls" (I don't know either of them, so not sure how they are used). OpenCV uses code snippets like `if(tegra is available) call special TEGRA function; else perform the open source openCV standard code;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for opencv dependencies

For libopencv4tegra 2.4.13 it uses cuda-npp-7-0 but doesn't use libvisionworks which is OpenVX implementation for Tegra

So, I think OpenCV for Tegra makes use of NPP and doesn't make use of OpenVX

Comment: NPP is used but no visionWorks.